# Keep user logged in after refresh browser for Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: javascript, microsoft-graph-api

I followed the tutorial to [Build JavaScript single-page apps with Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/javascript), and use it for my real project.

With this tutorial, I could able to create the web app for login user and create a calendar event. The problem is the session is always quickly expired as soon as I refresh so that I have to login again and again. Is there any way I can keep user still login after refresh browser. I wish it just like the google calendar id [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/quickstart/js) that can keep user signed in even after fresh browser. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the logged in user details. On refresh or the first visit to your site, first check to see if the details are available in local storage. If they are available, then log in the user automatically. Otherwise request the user to login and save the details in local storage.

Comment: is there something to do with access token ? since each enquiry request to Microsoft graph api need to verify token in background, and token key is provided by Microsoft graph?

Comment: after each successful login, it return some credential data related to user session and token, something like this `{authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/", uniqueId: "00000000-0000-0000-0a5e-6d6f09a46943", tenantId: "9188040d-6c67-4c5b-b112-36a304b66dad", scopes: Array(5), account: {…}, …}` I store it in localStroage and next time I do initialization with it, but I could not do any request with api saying something like 'public token is not a function'. Thanks

Comment: is the public key stored in localstorage too?